# Push httpProvider interceptor outside of config method

Tags: angularjs

For reasons that does not make sense to explain here I need to push an interceptor outside of config method. More specifically in the run method of the module. So I created a global reference to the httpProvider and then in the run method I push the interceptor. But the interceptor's responseError callback is never executed. If I put the same line inside the config method it works. In both cases I change the httpProvider using the reference.

Does anyone have any clue on that? How can I push an httpProvider interceptor outside of config method?

Comment: You can configure the services only in config method. run method will be executed after services so it couldn't configure the service

Answer (score 0):

As we know that all services/factories are singleton objects. They are instantiated only once. So we need to configure the interceptor before the  service instantiate.

The config function is useful to configure providers before they're actually created. The `config` method runs just after the angular app boostraps. It's the first method to run. So if you putt he interceptor in `config` it will modify the service before it's created.

But the run method will execute later. The run function could be useful to perform any kind of initialization after the objects instances registered in the module have already been created.  That's the reason why you're not finding it working.